# Python multiprocessing outside main module: slow computations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code that aims at multiprocessing at some inner part in some module that is NOT tha main.py. To make it simple, I have created a replica code that contains two files:  the main.py and the file f1_mod.py. My main.py would look something like:

```
import os
from time import time
import f1_mod

parallel = 1
N = 10000000

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    if not parallel:
        time_start = time()
        res = f1_mod.normal_exec( N )
        time_end =  time()
    
        print("-->time is ", time_end - time_start )
    else:
        time_start = time()
        res = f1_mod.parallel_exec( N )
        time_end =  time()
    
        print("-->time is ", time_end - time_start )

    for j in range( 100 ):
        print( res[j] )

    else:  
        print("--> CHILD PROCESS ID: ", os.getpid() )
        pass
```

and the f1_mod.py would be:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


def pool_worker_function( k, args ):    
    d = args[0]        
    return d["p"]*( k**2 ) + d["x"]**2     
        
def single_thread_exec( N ):    
    a = list( np.linspace( 0, N, N ) )    
    d = { "p": 0.2, "x": 0.5 } 
    result =  []    
    for k in a:        
        result.append( d["p"]*( k**2) + d["x"]**2 )
    return result

def parallel_exec( N ):
    number_processors      = mp.cpu_count()
    number_used_processors = number_processors - 1

    #try pool map method            
    from itertools import repeat      

    pool    = mp.Pool( processes = number_used_processors )   

    d = { "p": 0.2, "x": 0.5 } 
    a = list( np.linspace( 0, N, N ) )          
    
    args = ( d, )     
    number_tasks = number_used_processors              

    chuncks = []    
    n_chunck = int( ( len(a) - 1 )/number_tasks )
    for j in range( 0, number_tasks ):
    
        if ( j == number_tasks - 1 ):
            chuncks.append( a[ j*n_chunck: ] )
        else:
            chuncks.append( a[ j*n_chunck: j*n_chunck + n_chunck ]   ) 
      
    result = pool.starmap( pool_worker_function, zip( a, repeat( args ) ) )              
    pool.close()        
    pool.join()           
    return result
```

I check that both the serial and parallelized versions give the same results, except that the serial version is **much faster** than the multiprocessed one. In my real code, this is sometimes the case, and the "args" tuple entering the worker function actually contains a big object data container, with a much bigger dictionary that is used to read data from to perform the operations. Can anyone explain why do I observe this behaviour (i.e. slow performance when multiprocessing)? Data needs to be passed to the worker function every time, and actually this makes the worker function to take a lot of arguments are maybe is what slows the code giving the IPC takin place ? (¿?)

The "repeat" in the args passed to the worker is used since all arguments passed by the tuple have to be the same for each worker, the only iterable is the list "a". Does anyone know how to make an efficient multiprocessing of this? Also, note that multiprocessing does not happen at the "main.py" level, but rather at "deep" functions in some module within the logic of the code. I would appreciate some help here to better understand how this multiprocessing works! I am using a 4 core machine under Windows OS, and I know now Windows does not support "fork" like behaviour when using multiprocessing. However, running the code in Ubuntu on my machine seems to be very slow too! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess for the current code : you don't do enough work in `pool_worker_function` to offset the cost of communication/synchronization.

I may be wrong, but your code seems half finished : the `chunks` variable is never used. Anyway, passing a big arrays (your chunks) around wouldn't probably be the best solution.

You may try to pass start/len parameters to your `pool_worker_function`, then create the array and do the computation there, but I'm not 100% sure it will be enough to offset the communication cost for the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually my real code has a much more complicated worker function, with a big loop over indices performing calculations... My problem involves a list of keys representing the unknowns, and shared objects passed as arguments, namely Numpy arrays etc... I have used the chunk_size as calculated above, but it does not seem to make any significant difference...

Comment: Maybe should try `starmap_async` instead of `starmap` and provide a `chunksize` as third argument.

Comment: Does starmap_async return the results in order ? It is extremely important for me that this is the case.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) is not super explicit on this. As it works like `map`, I guess it would keep the order...